Дано целое число N (> 1), а также первый член A и разность D арифметической прогрессии
Дана простая задача: дано целое число N (> 1), а также первый член A и разность D арифметической прогрессии. Сформировать и вывести массив размера N, содержащий N первых членов данной прогрессии:
A,    A + D,    A + 2·D,    A + 3·D,    … .
Сталкиваюсь с проблемой в 6ой строке: для r invalid syntax, не понимаю как её решить, многое перепробовал, интернет не помог, преподаватели тем более. Подскажите как обойти ошибку или какие материалы посмотреть, чтобы стало понятно почему не принимает код?
N=10
A=1
D=3
r=[]
A=[i for i in range(N)
   r.append(A+i*D) ]
print(*A)


Создание нужного списка может выглядеть так:
N=10
A=1
D=3
r=[A+i*D for i in range(N)]
print(*r)


Я немножко изменил ваш код, потому что вы, наверно, хотели сделать так:
N=10
A=1
D=3
r=[]
for i in range(N):         # <--- здесь разница
    r.append(A+i*D)        # <--- здесь маленькая разница — удалена квадратная скобка
print(*r)                  # <--- и здесь маленькая разница - r вместо A

Вывод:

1 4 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28



Объяснение:
Вы не хотите переписать переменную A (созданную командой A=1) командой
A=[i for i in range(N)
   r.append(A+i*D) ]           # не правильный синтаксис, должно быть if ... или for ...

а постепенно заполнить список r членами арифметической последовательности.
Значит, надо убрать часть A=[i  и заключительную квадратную скобку ], добавить двоеточие (:) после range(N), получая таким образом правильный цикл for:
for i in range(N):
    r.append(A+i*D)

Но и, естественно, после этого вы хотели вывести на экран не А, а r...
